# Print a diamond of stars using simple for loops

Tags: c#, loops

Required output is:

```
******
**  **
*    *
**  **
******
```

I have written the following code to achieve it:

```
int n = 5;

for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (int j =n-1; j >= n-i; j--)
    {
        if ((i == j && j > i) || (j == i && i > j))
            Console.Write("*");
        else
            Console.Write("3");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--)
{
    for (int j =  i; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if ((i == j && j > i) || (j == i && i > j))
            Console.Write("*");
        else
            Console.Write("3");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

But instead my code is printing:

```
33333
3333
333
33
3
3
33
333
3333
33333
```

How can I fix my code to print a diamond of stars?

Comment: ******
**   ** 
*     *
**   **
******

Comment: You do realize that `(i == j && j > i)` is ***always*** false?

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just do it in a simple way?

```
Console.Writeline("******");
Console.Writeline("**  **");
Console.Writeline("*    *");
Console.Writeline("**  **");
Console.Writeline("******");
```

Comment: no sir, i want to use some logic that print diamond,

Comment: Then you should really expand your question and explain that logic, it's very unclear what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int number = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
    var starsCount = 1 + Math.Abs(Math.Floor(number / 2.0) - i);
    var spacesCount = 1 + Math.Floor(number / 2.0) - starsCount;
    var output = "";

    for (int j = 0; j < starsCount; j++)
        output += "*";
    for (int k = 0; k < spacesCount; k++)
        output += "  ";
    for (int m = 0; m < starsCount; m++)
        output += "*";

    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: sir it is great, but can you tell me please how did u start to think about this problem, i was using if-else conditions, more then 5 days i m trying to solve this but i could not do, nowdays my uni is off so can u share any where i can build up my knowladge and could make strong my logics.

Comment: It is all about how you analyze the problem, I  divided the problem into two side: left and right, and built the logic considering that. This is logic that cannot be taught, it is experience gained over time, the more problems you solve the more you know :)

Comment: i print just diamond with your code but here it is
int number = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
 {var spacesCount = 1 + Math.Abs(Math.Floor(number / 2.0) - i);
var starsCount = 1 + Math.Floor(number / 2.0) - spacesCount;
var output = " ";
for (var j = 0; j <spacesCount; j++)
 output += " ";
for (int k = 0; k< starsCount; k++)
 output += " *";
 for (int m = 0; m < spacesCount; m++)
  output += " ";
                 Console.WriteLine(output);
      }
 Console.ReadLine();
  }
 }

Comment: int number = 10;for (int i = 0; i < number; i++){
var spacesCount = 1 + Math.Abs(Math.Floor(number / 2.0) - i);
var starsCount = 1 + Math.Floor(number / 2.0) - spacesCount;
var last = starsCount - 1.0;
 var output = ""; for (int j = 0; j < spacesCount; j++) output += " ";
 for (int k = 0; k < starsCount; k++){ for (int g = 0; g < starsCount; g++){
 if ((k == 0  && g == 0) || (k==last && g==last))output += "*"; else output += " "; /* if ( k == last &&  g == last)  output += "*";else
output += " "; */ }} for (int m = 0; m < spacesCount; m++)output += " "; Console.WriteLine(output);}}

Comment: @ Tha'er Al-Ajlouni please can you check it , i want to print diamond now like 
  *
*   *
  *
but having little issue.

Comment: its not my homework, trying to learn .